# How to trigger calls to .serializeWithType() of a class implementing JsonSerializable in Jackson?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

This is Jackson 2.2.x.

I have a class implementing [`JsonSerializable`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializable.html); there are two methods to implement for this interface, `serialize()` and `serializeWithType()`.

I want to test {de,}serialization of this class, and I can trigger calls to `serialize()` easily; not, however, `serializeWithType()`.

The [javadoc for this latter method](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializable.html#serializeWithType(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeSerializer)) says that this method is called

> *[...]* when additional type information is expected to be included in serialization, for deserialization to use.

I just don't understand what this means...

How do I set up a test environment so that this method be called? Note that the JSON to be serialized can be of any type except object (ie, boolean, number, string, array are all valid types).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This method is used when you want to use polymorphism

```
public class A {
    ...
}

public class B extends A {
    ...
}

public class C extends A {
    ...
}
```

If you serialize an instance of C and then try to deserialize the resulting json but only knowing that its a sub-type of A :

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new C());
final A deserialized = objectMapper.readValue(json, A.class);
```

You need something to be stored within the resulting JSON to keep the real type of the serialized object.

This can be enabled either using `@JsonTypeInfo` on your class, or by calling `enableDefaultTyping` on your `ObjectMapper`.

This is a sample test case using JUnit & Mockito

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

public class SerializeWithTypeTest {

    private JsonSerializable serializable = mock(JsonSerializable.class);

    @Test
    public void shouldCallSerializeWithType() throws Exception {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);

        objectMapper.writeValueAsString(serializable);

        // make sure serializeWithType is called once
        verify(serializable, times(1)).serializeWithType(any(), any(), any());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Jackson 2 [is completely incompatible with Jackson 1](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonRelease20), and `JsonSerializableWithType` (Now deprecated and unusable) is an interface from Jackson 1 which led to the presence of `serializeWithType()` in Jackson 2.

`serializeWithType()` is called when additional type information is expected to be included, which means that an annotation (`JsonTypeInfo`) is specifying the class `property` for deserialization delegation, when polymorphism is used. This method will then be called with the additional type information within a `TypeSerializer`, which may be written with a type prefix:

```
/* (.., .., TypeSerializer typeSer) */ {
    typeSer.writeTypePrefixForScalar(.., .., ThisClass.class);
}
```

By annotating the class with `@JsonTypeInfo`, you will be able to specify serializing with the type information:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(name = "typeint", value = MyInt.class),
        @Type(name = "typefloat", value = MyFloat.class)
})
public interface MyNumber {}

@JsonTypeName("typeint")
public MyInt implements MyNumber {}

@JsonTypeName("typefloat")
public MyFloat implements MyNumber {}
```

Then the values `typeint` and `typefloat` will be set in the property named `type`. When you deserialize a `MyNumber`, it will be based on polymorphism. [Thomas Maurel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26753948/3622940) demonstrates a straightforward approach to test by serializing the object as string and deseralizing it.

Comment: You would think if Jackson 2 is completely incompatible with Jackson 1, that this would have been an opportunity to make it work properly. Jackson is stupidly complicated to get working compared to other languages/frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`JsonTypeInfo`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html) annotation on your class. It should trigger calling `serializeWithType()`. It is used to store info about type which is required for polymorphic types or to link abstract type and matching concrete implementation.