# JSON Jackson - exception when serializing a polymorphic class with custom serializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm currently migrating some code from Jackson 1.x to Jackson 2.5 json mapper and came a long a problem that wasn't there in 1.x.

This is the setup (see code below):

- interface IPet
- class Dog implements IPet
- IPet is annotated with @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes
- class Human has a property of type IPet that is annotated with @JsonSerialize(using=CustomPetSerializer.class)

**The problem:**
If I serialize an instance of Dog it works as expected (also the type info is added to the json string by Jackson).
However when I serialize an instance of the Human class an exception is thrown saying:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Type id handling
>   not implemented for type com.pet.Dog (through reference chain:
>   com.Human["pet"])

The serialize(...) method of the CustomPetSerializer class is not invoked (tested using a breakpoint).

**The code:**

IPet implementation:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
     @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Dog.class,    name="dog")
    //,@JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Cat.class,  name="cat")
    //more subtypes here...
})
public interface IPet
{
    public Long getId();
    public String getPetMakes();
}
```

Dog implementation:

```
public class Dog implements IPet
{
    @Override
    public String getPetMakes()
    {
        return "Wuff!";
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId()
    {
        return 777L;
    }
}
```

Human who owns a dog:

```
public class Human
{
    private IPet pet = new Dog();

    @JsonSerialize(using=CustomPetSerializer.class)
    public IPet getPet()
    {
        return pet;
    }
}
```

CustomPetSerializer implementation:

```
public class CustomPetSerializer extends JsonSerializer<IPet>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(IPet value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        if(value != null && value.getId() != null)
        {
            Map<String,Object> style = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            style.put("age", "7");
            gen.writeObject(style);
        }
    }
}
```

JUnit test method:

```
@Test
public void testPet() throws JsonProcessingException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Human human = new Human();

    //works as expcected
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(human.getPet());
    Assert.assertNotNull(json);
    Assert.assertTrue(json.equals("{\"type\":\"dog\",\"id\":777,\"petMakes\":\"Wuff!\"}"));

    //throws exception: Type id handling not implemented for type com.pet.Dog (through reference chain: com.Human["pet"])
    json = mapper.writeValueAsString(human);    //exception is thrown here
    Assert.assertNotNull(json);
    Assert.assertTrue(json.contains("\"age\":\"7\""));
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You'll need to additionally override `serializeWithType` within you `CustomPetSerializer` because `IPet` is polymorphic. That's also the reason why `serialize` is not called. Check [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672297/how-to-trigger-calls-to-serializewithtype-of-a-class-implementing-jsonseriali) that explains in detail when `serializeWithType` is called. For instance, your `serializeWithType` implementation might look something like this:

```
@Override
public void serializeWithType(IPet value, JsonGenerator gen, 
        SerializerProvider provider, TypeSerializer typeSer) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

  typeSer.writeTypePrefixForObject(value, gen);
  serialize(value, gen, provider); // call your customized serialize method
  typeSer.writeTypeSuffixForObject(value, gen);
}
```

which will print `{"pet":{"type":"dog":{"age":"7"}}}` for your `Human` instance.

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue, I have posted my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72089765/7584240, if you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some suggestions?

Comment: `writeTypePrefixForObject` is deprecated as of Jackson 2.9

Answer (score 23):

Since Jackson 2.9 `writeTypePrefixForObject()` and `writeTypeSuffixForObject()` have been deprecated (I'm unclear why). It seems under the new approach it would now be:

```
@Override
public void serializeWithType(IPet value, JsonGenerator gen, 
        SerializerProvider provider, TypeSerializer typeSer) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

  WritableTypeId typeId = typeSer.typeId(value, START_OBJECT);
  typeSer.writeTypePrefix(gen, typeId);
  serialize(value, gen, provider); // call your customized serialize method
  typeSer.writeTypeSuffix(gen, typeId);
}
```

So an extra line now, so not sure why it's a step forward, perhaps it's more efficient reusing the `typeId` object.

**Source:** Jackson's [ObjectNode](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.java#L314) class currently in master. Not the best source but couldn't see any upgrade docs explaining what to do.

Comment: I requested clarification of the deprecation at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2025.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `END_OBJECT` in your last line? So no reuse of `typeId`?

Comment: @mat3e, I don't think so, because `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase#serializeWithType` does it like this too.